# Is it normal for the standard deviation to have fluctuations

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Is it normal for the standard deviation to have fluctuations or does it always have to decrease as the number of samples increases?

I'm running an experiment and analyzing the standard deviation. It turns out that with 30 samples it is showing a standard deviation smaller than with 100 samples. However, the difference is small. This is normal? Whenever the number of samples is increased, does the standard deviation have to decrease?

example

43,39343268 -   100 samples

41,70797952 -   30 samples

43,22036557 -   50 samples

I'm calculating the profit made in 600 minutes. The profit is the result of several distributions, as the arrival time of each customer can vary, which type of customer and processing time, with each type of customer paying a different amount... therefore for every 600 minutes (one day of work), the profit will be different.

example profit 10 runs:

590
610
560
620
620
510
630
610
620
600

Comment: You can use Student's T-test statistic to determine if the different sample sets are unique (from each other). Compare the first group of 30 to the added group of 70. What is the history of all of the samples. Were they all created at the same time without changes in the settings or could newly made parts have been recently added that may be slighly different from the others? (Not sure where the 50 fits in.) Even if the equipment is cleaned between runs could change settings, changes in the environment, changes in incoming material too.

Comment: I'm calculating the profit made in 600 minutes. The profit is the result of several distributions, as the arrival time of each customer can vary, which type of customer and processing time, with each type of customer paying a different amount... therefore for every 600 minutes (one day of work), the profit will be different.

Comment: If the customer gets a discount for bulk purchase that will change the profit. If there is more than one product the markup should be equivalent to equilibrate the profit. If you have to pay for credit card purchases compared to incoming checks or debit card purchases, then that will change your profit. If revenue comes from around the world, changes in monetary value will likely change your profit. If you sell different number of units each day and you have a fixed cost of operation, that will change your daily profit. What you calculate is what you calculate.

Comment: A small number of samples could cluster around the mean, leading to a small standard deviation.

Comment: But wouldn't it be correct to decrease the standard deviation with increasing samples?

Comment: Standard deviation doesn't have to increase or decrease as the sample size increases. It's a parameter that helps shape a distribution, so you should actually expect it to remain about the same. Standard error should decrease, since it's equal to $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$, which decreases as $n\to \infty$.